# Struggling with Mixed Basis Set Inclusion for IRC Calculations

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian

I'm trying to compute the IRC for a W complex, and I'm using Def2TZVP for W and 6-311G** for the rest of the atoms. However, when I include the mixed basis set, Gaussian 16 generates a syntax error.

I tried quite a few different ways, but none of them worked.
I used M062X/gen pseudo=read then include the basis sets at the end of the input file (picture attached)[image]

Then I used this method (picture attached)[image]
However, none of them worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the output error.

"IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC-IRC
Reading IRC summary table definitions from the input file.
DfStat: QParse returned with an error. IStat= -1
QPErr --- A syntax error was detected in the input line.

Last state= ""
TCursr= 122 LCursr= 0
Parse error in Link 123."

Comment: +1 but please remove the screensots and replace them with `code blocks`.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest you misformatting the "IRC summary table definitions". From your screenshots, it appears you don't include these at all. Can you try running without `Report=Read`, which is requesting that this be read from the input?

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for your comments.
Did you mean Guess=Read?

Comment: You did not ping @Tyberius so he might not have seen your question.

Comment: I do mean `Report=Read`, which is an option you added to the `IRC` keyword.

Comment: @Tyberius Ah, I see... I will try to run without it and see if that works.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks Nike! I'm new to Stackflow. Still figuring out how it's working.

Comment: @user8769 welcome to the Matter Modeling Stack Exchange! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! Please ask and answer lots of questions and become part of our active community !!!

Comment: Why not def2TZVP for everything? 6-311G is a valence double-zeta basis set claiming to be triple-zeta.